# How do I do backup and (point-in-time) recovery for etcd?

Tags: backup, recovery, auditing, point-in-time, etcd

I understand that etcd stores its data in some kind of distributed log.

Are there tools to back up these logs and do recovery from them? Does that also support point-in-time recovery (and how far back can we go)?

Extra points: do these logs also contain audit trails (i.e. who updated the data, assuming client authentication is in place)?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to read all existing keys into a file, then use that file by reading in and adding all keys to restore.  There is an open source solution that takes that approach here https://github.com/fanhattan/etcd-backup. I don't think audit trails are included.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may answer your question: 
https://labs.consol.de/kubernetes/2018/05/25/kubeadm-backup.html

It does automated backup of etcd as a Cronjob, so if you have it backup once an hour, that'd be like point in time recovery?

You could also use Heptio ARK on a schedule to do similar I believe.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRPNuT080Hk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take etcd backup in JSON format that you can easily restore to any cluster, you can use this simple backup and restore utility: [simple-etcd-backup-restore](https://github.com/abdullahkhawer/simple-etcd-backup-restore)

This utility makes the backup and restore process easier and faster. You can also compress/decompress the backup file and upload/download it on/from AWS S3 bucket. The size of backup files also gets smaller. Data in the backup files stays readable as well.